# Magento CSS cannot be updated

Tags: php, css, magento

I'm Trying to replace my style files with new files that have been implemented on another machine, but nothing changed

I Flushed all caches (images and CSS) ,  Disabled Mergeing CSS Files and run the compilation

Comment: Flushing should be enough. Maybe you updated the wrong files if you have many themes/package?

Comment: No It is correct, because it is running successfully on another machine and  I'm using the same files !

Comment: Do you have another cache, like APC, memcache, or Redis running?

Comment: Did you place the new CSS file in the skin directory for the correct theme? Check which theme you're using (System>configuration>design) and make sure the CSS is the skin/frontend/your/theme/css/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what files you have overridden and your current theme design this will be hard do debug, but one this I can suggest doing is to disable all caches, disable merging and disable compilation. This should help you to see if you are changing the correct files. If after this step your changes are not being made then you are changing the wrong files.

After that what you can look at doing is simply updating the file you think should be called and adding some weird css like adding a green border around everything, but obviously this is not great on a live site so you could but in place a maintenance page to all up your own ip.